# Problem with running the code for the circular barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I try to run the code for a circular barplot provided by https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/299-circular-stacked-barplot.html

```
# library
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)

# Create dataset
data <- data.frame(
  individual=paste( "Mister ", seq(1,60), sep=""),
  group=c( rep('A', 10), rep('B', 30), rep('C', 14), rep('D', 6)) ,
  value1=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T),
  value2=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T),
  value3=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T)
)

# Transform data in a tidy format (long format)
data <- data %>% gather(key = "observation", value="value", -c(1,2)) 

# Set a number of 'empty bar' to add at the end of each group
empty_bar <- 2
nObsType <- nlevels(as.factor(data$observation))
to_add <- data.frame( matrix(NA, empty_bar*nlevels(data$group)*nObsType, ncol(data)) )
colnames(to_add) <- colnames(data)
to_add$group <- rep(levels(data$group), each=empty_bar*nObsType )
data <- rbind(data, to_add)
data <- data %>% arrange(group, individual)
data$id <- rep( seq(1, nrow(data)/nObsType) , each=nObsType)

# Get the name and the y position of each label
label_data <- data %>% group_by(id, individual) %>% summarize(tot=sum(value))
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
angle <- 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar     # I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)
label_data$hjust <- ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle <- ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

# prepare a data frame for base lines
base_data <- data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(start=min(id), end=max(id) - empty_bar) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(title=mean(c(start, end)))

# prepare a data frame for grid (scales)
grid_data <- base_data
grid_data$end <- grid_data$end[ c( nrow(grid_data), 1:nrow(grid_data)-1)] + 1
grid_data$start <- grid_data$start - 1
grid_data <- grid_data[-1,]

# Make the plot
p <- ggplot(data) +      

  # Add the stacked bar
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=observation), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE) +

  # Add a val=100/75/50/25 lines. I do it at the beginning to make sur barplots are OVER it.
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 0, xend = start, yend = 0), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 50, xend = start, yend = 50), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 100, xend = start, yend = 100), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 150, xend = start, yend = 150), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 200, xend = start, yend = 200), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +

  # Add text showing the value of each 100/75/50/25 lines
  ggplot2::annotate("text", x = rep(max(data$id),5), y = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200), label = c("0", "50", "100", "150", "200") , color="grey", size=6 , angle=0, fontface="bold", hjust=1) +

  ylim(-150,max(label_data$tot, na.rm=T)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
  ) +
  coord_polar() +

  # Add labels on top of each bar
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=tot+10, label=individual, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) +

  # Add base line information
  geom_segment(data=base_data, aes(x = start, y = -5, xend = end, yend = -5), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=0.6 , inherit.aes = FALSE )  +
  geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label=group), hjust=c(1,1,0,0), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=4, fontface="bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)


# Save at png
ggsave(p, file="output.png", width=10, height=10)
```

Then, I ran into several error messages. 
Three from running the code under

## Get the name and the y position of each label

Warning message:
Factor `individual` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na`

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, hjust, value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, angle, value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1

And two from

## Make the plot

Warning message:
In max(label_data$tot, na.rm = T) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, xend

Can anyone help me with these errors?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get any errors when I run the code. I get a couple warnings but everything runs fine and I get the plot at the end.

Comment: I reinstall the R and Rstudio and the problem is solved. Thanks anyway.